# How collection referencing works in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First time i am trying to use refrence in mongoose , so i am trying to understand if i want to save template with user id , Do we need to get `createdBy` value from client or how it will be inserted into `templateSchema`. basically i want to save user id `_id` when user save template.I was able to save template but i did not get any error and `createdBy` property did not saved to template collection. Any layman explanation to understand refrencing in mongoose and how i can make it work with below code.

user.js

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true}},
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  type: String,
  groups:[{type: String, ref: 'Group', required: false}]
},
  {
    toObject: {
      virtuals: true
    },
    toJSON: {
      virtuals: true
    }
  });
```

template.js

```
var User = require('../user/user.model.js');

var TemplateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: String, required: true},
  name: String,
  id: String,
  appliesTo: [],
  properties: [],
  createdBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
 });
```

templateCtrl.js

```
var eTemplate = require('./template.model');

var templatesJavaClass = {
          "_id": 12586,
          "name": "Java Class",
          "id": "javaClass",
          "appliesTo": [
              "bpmn:UserTask"
          ],
          "properties": [{
              "label": "Java Package Name",
              "type": "String",
              "editable": true,
              "binding": {
                  "type": "property",
                  "name": "camunda:class"
              }
          }],
        "createdBy": "user1"
      }

 var template = new eTemplate(templatesJavaClass);

 template.save(function(error){
  console.log("successfully saved template");
  if (error){
    console.log(error);
  }
 });
```

Comment: where are how are you trying to save the user _id in the template document?

Comment: thats what i am trying to understand when you use reference to other collection do we need to send id from client in my case to `templateSchema`

Comment: you need to save the user _id in createdby field, just like other fields. Do you have the user _id ?

Comment: ok as you said i updated by question so if i used createdBy in json , i got below error while saving `{ [ValidationError: Template validation failed]
  errors:
   { createdBy:
      { [CastError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "user1" at path "createdBy"]
        message: 'Cast to ObjectID failed for value "user1" at path "createdBy"',
`

Comment: because that must be an ObjectId and not string, what is user1?

Comment: can you please explain what is actually happening here `createdBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135211/discussion-between-ravi-shankar-and-hussain).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put user `_id` in `createdBy` field of `template` document while creating/saving it.

Also, make sure it is of Type `ObjectId` and not `string`. Otherwise you might get `Cast Error`.

Try this:

```
var templatesJavaClass = {
    "_id": 12586,
    "name": "Java Class",
    "id": "javaClass",
    "appliesTo": [
        "bpmn:UserTask"
    ],
    "properties": [{
        "label": "Java Package Name",
        "type": "String",
        "editable": true,
        "binding": {
            "type": "property",
            "name": "camunda:class"
        }
    }],
  //save users _id in createdBy field
  "createdBy": user1._id;//assuming user1 is the users document
}

var template = new eTemplate(templatesJavaClass);

template.save(function(error){
    console.log("successfully saved template");
    if (error){
      console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: see here we will get the createdBy from client that will pe part of json object how we will map it to user's _id

Comment: in any case, you need to put the _id of the user in createdBy field.

Comment: we can discuss on chat too here :http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135211/discussion-between-ravi-shankar-and-hussain

Comment: so you are saying as i mentioned `user1` if its part of object it will save the template  ?, currently its hard coded as string

Comment: dont have access to what? Also, dont hardcode it as string, in that place give the _id of the user. Atleast tell me how you are getting the user1 object? so that i can help you

Comment: dont have access to stackoverflow chat . user1 will be be property of object object.createdBy that will be posted from client.

Comment: what do you mean by posted from client? Is client sending request to the server to save the template? If yes, can you show the request body. or if anywhere are you saving users `_id` in sessions or something